# Custom section view is not updated after row delete

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm facing the problem that I can't update the section header in my tableview after deleting a row. I don't know why this doesn't work when I'm using a custom view for the section header. The section header should show the amount of entries in my section header. I don't want to reload the tableView, because the causes delete animation issues. I just want to update only the
"Total Entries"

Can anyone help me please ?

```
// Load view for section
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = JournalSectionHeaderView()
            headerView.dateLabel.text =  groupedEntries[section].first?.endDate!.getDateAsReadableText()
            headerView.sectionTotalLabel.text = "Total Entries:" + groupedEntries[section].count
            return headerView
        }

//Delete the row
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                let entry = groupedEntries[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                dbController.context.delete(entry)
                groupedEntries[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                dbController.saveContext()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `UITableView.reloadSections(_:with:)` in your `commit` method?

Comment: Yes, but this leads to an animation issue @RobertCrabtree . The row delete animation looks a little bit weird when I call the reloadSection method. This should not have an impact on the delete animation.

Comment: You need to call deleteRows and reloadSections inside of tableView.performBatchUpdates

Comment: @RobertCrabtree thank you so much! That solved my problem!